# How to call "npm install" from Inno Setup?

Tags: node.js, command-line, npm, inno-setup

I'm writing an installer in Inno Setup which installs Node.js, extracts a zip file containing all the node project files, and then needs to install the node app using `npm install`.

The manual process consists of opening a command prompt, browsing to the directory where these files are (in my case extracted to its Program Files folder corresponding with the `{app}` folder setting), and then running that exact command line `npm install --quiet`. However, when doing this in Inno Setup, it fails...

```
function InstallNodeApp: Integer;
var
  C: String;
begin
  C:= 'npm install --quiet';
  if not Exec(C, '', ExpandConstant('{app}'), SW_SHOWNORMAL, ewWaitUntilTerminated, Result) then begin
    Result:= -1;
  end;
end;
```

I've tried putting `--quiet` in the parameters as well as calling `cmd.exe` with this command line as a parameter, and many other combinations of attempts, but nothing is working - the execution just fails. The error I get is always `The system cannot find the file specified.`.

How can I perform this node install while receiving the result/exit code?

Comment: Assuming that the `npm` is the executable, you should write something like `Exec('npm', 'install --quiet', ExpandConstant('{app}'), SW_SHOWNORMAL, ewWaitUntilTerminated, Result)`, where `npm` is expected to be found either in `{app}` folder or e.g. path registered by the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: @TLama `npm` isn't an executable, that's why I can't get it working. At least it's not an executable in this folder. I don't know anything about `Node.js` and `npm` but I'm trying to replicate what's done in the command line with Inno Setup.

Comment: Note that command prompt uses Windows Shell and as such it can run not only executables (e.g. batch files). Having said that, a closer equivalent is the `ShellExec` function in Inno Setup. For sure I can tell, if that `npm` is not an executable, use `ShellExec` function.

Comment: Glad it helped! :) Feel free to post an answer... [have no extra time]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I was using `Exec` but because of the nature of `npm`, it needed to use a shell command. So instead, as TLama mentioned in the comments, I used `ShellExec` and everything worked.

```
function InstallNodeApp: Integer;
var
  C, P, D: String;
begin
  C:= 'npm';
  P:= 'install --silent';
  D:= ExpandConstant('{app}');
  if not ShellExec('', C, P, D, SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, Result) then begin
    Result:= -1;
  end;
end;
```